# Writing apps for Android and Apple phone simultaneously

Tags: android, app, apple

So, recently I have been looking into developing apps. I joined a school group who wanted to develop an app, problem being that I had an Android phone and my friends all had Apple phones. I know of Unity, but I was wondering if there might be a better way to develop apps for Android and Apple simultaneously. While having a built-in 3d engine would be nice, it's not necessary if it would be easier to develop an app on a platform without a 3d engine. As of now the only languages I feel comfortable in are Javascript, CPP, and Python, hence I am open to pretty much any language though any of those 3 would be preferable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often achieved by a "progressive web app" (PWA), in which all the functionality is written in Javascript. Apple support them via "pin to home screen": https://superpwa.com/doc/test-pwa-ios-devices/

Note that both the Apple and Google Play stores charge fees to distribute apps, and it's much harder to "sideload" apps to your friends on Apple. They would have to be rapidly expiring development versions.

Otherwise, it's a pretty difficult area. There is Xamarin and MAUI, which are really intended for doing cross-platform apps from a Windows/C# background.